# how to declare the Size of message in PROMELA?

Tags: promela

Is there any method to specify the size of message?. For example if i want to send message data through channel AB then how can I specify the size of data in PROMELA language?

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for declaring a channel is, for example:

```
chan ab = [16] of { short }
```

`ab` is the identifier bound to the channel. `16` is the number of messages in the channel.  `short` is the data type of each message.

When you specify the message type you have a number of additional options:

```
char ab = [16] of { byte, short, bit }
```

which creates a channel with each message being: byte, short, and bit.  In such a case it is often better to create a new type with:

```
typedef message {
  byte operator;
  short data;
  bit what;
};
```

and then

```
chan ab = [16] of { message }
```